# The suprema of topological groups

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

We know that if $G $ is a group and $A = \{ \tau_{i} \}_{i \in I}$ is a family of topological groups on group $G$ so that $\forall i \in I$ , $( G , \tau_{i} )$ is a topological group, and  $\tau = \bigvee \tau_{i}$ ( sup $\tau_{i}$), then $( G , \tau)$  is a topological group.

Is it right to say:

withs mentioned  conditions , $\bigwedge \tau_{i} = \tau $ ( inf $\tau_{i}$ ) is a topological group.

Comment: I think you mean that $A$ is a family of topologies on $G$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a counterexample: [page 116 of this paper by Samuel](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1948-064-01/S0002-9947-1948-0025717-6/S0002-9947-1948-0025717-6.pdf) has an example of two (!) group topologies on a set whose intersection (i.e. infimum) is **not** a group topology.